# Saving user data to internal memory - Apple TV Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-tv

I am trying to save access token with in the application registry and getting saved success fully, but after rebooting the device and coming back to the device registry is getting cleared and user is taken back to the authentication page.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken, forKey: "apiToken")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

let apiToken = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "apiToken")
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. In the title you mention internal memory, then in the body you mention application registry, but your actual code is using `UserDefaults`, which is saving its data to the file system, so its data is persisted between device reboots. So is your goal to persist data on the file system and if so, how come your code doesn't achieve this?

Comment: You also need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic, since the `apiToken` and `refreshToken` properties are clearly custom properties, so you need to show their declarations.

Answer (score 1):

To save a value to UserDefaults you need to create a value key

Unless you've already created some extension which is adding an additional property to UserDefaults.. "apiToken" that you've not shared here, you'll need to create it like this

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken, forKey: "apiToken")
```

You will then be able to retrieve this from

```
let apiToken = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "apiToken")
```